# How do I set a window "always on top"?

Tags: window

No matter which window I'm working on, the one I choose will be always appearing in front of all. Of course, I would have to set its size.

Comment: With your reputation of 576 I think this must be an important question but frankly I'm confused why clicking on a window moving it to the foreground is a bad thing. After all if I clicked on a window and it remained in the background I would be most annoyed. Have you tried compiz windows manager: [www.compiz.org](http://www.compiz.org/) for fancier window control? I'm still not sure what features you are searching for though.

Comment: For gnome shell: http://imgur.com/a/94rhI

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix see my answer and you may understand my question. As an example of its use, imaging you're in a video conference and you want to keep working using all the screen.

Comment: @Vitor my humblest apologies-I'm video conference challenged. I see you found your answer though and all is good right?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No problem, and I found the solution. Another use is watching some live sport game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimize the desired window, right click next to the top menu and select `always on top`

[image]

Comment: a command to open onboard virtual keyboard always on top in a terminal?

Comment: This doesn't work if app doesn't provide title bar decoration. Correction, using `Alt+Space` provides the menu.